# Issues with Model-Level Django Templates

Tags: django-templates

I'm trying to customize my model's "edit" template to output plaintext values instead of form fields. I'm following instructions in the Django documentation and have searched on this without any luck.

The template I'm trying to override is change_form.html, and for some reason, I can't override app-level or model-level templates. I CAN override at the project-level, however, that is not a solution. I do have the directory in my TEMPLATE_DIRS in settings.py. My templates path looks like:
templates/admin/app/model/change_form.html (Yes, I am using lowercase model names.)

As sort of a workaround, I'm currently adding something to urls.py to use a specific template. I'd prefer to use the built-in logic though. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I had simply forgotten I'd specified a different app_label for my model. Therefore, the templates weren't being overridden, beginning at the application level. I changed the application directory name in my templates path and it works.